# PHP Reflection -- is this a bug or expected behavior?

Tags: php, reflection

I am creating a class that uses ReflectionProperty and am getting strange results.

Essentially, calling `$reflectionProperty->getType()->getName()` is returning the value of *some entirely unrelated array*.  It does this under seemingly random conditions.

See below:

```php
// this will be used as a type hinted property.
class DummyClass {
    public function __construct($arr) {}
}


// a class that sets its property values reflectively
class BaseClass {
    /** @var ReflectionProperty[] */
    private static $publicProps = [];

    /**
     * Gets public ReflectionProperties of the concrete class, and caches them
     * so we do not need to perform reflection again for this concrete class.
     *
     * @return ReflectionProperty[]
     * @throws ReflectionException
     */
    private function getPublicProps(){
        if (!static::$publicProps) {
            $concreteClass = get_class($this);
            static::$publicProps = (new ReflectionClass($concreteClass))
                ->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
        }
        return static::$publicProps;
    }

    /**
     * For each public property in this class set value to the corresponding value from $propArr.
     *
     * @param $propArr
     * @throws ReflectionException
     */
    public function __construct($propArr) {
        $concreteClass = get_class($this);
        echo "Creating new instance of $concreteClass<br>";
        foreach ($this->getPublicProps() as $prop) {
            // get which property to set, its class, and value to pass to constructor
            $propName = $prop->getName();
            $propClass = $prop->getType()->getName();
            $propValue = $propArr[$propName];
            $propValueStr = var_export($propValue, true);
            // print out what we are about to do, and assert $propClass is correct.
            echo "---Setting: ->$propName = new $propClass($propValueStr)<br>";
            assert($propClass === "DummyClass", "$propClass !== DummyClass");
            // create the instance and assign it
            $refClass = new ReflectionClass($propClass);
            $this->$propName = $refClass->newInstanceArgs([$propValue]);
        }
    }
}

// a concrete implementation of the above class, with only 1 type hinted property.
class ConcreteClass extends BaseClass {
    public DummyClass $prop1;
}

// should create an instance of ConcreteClass
// with ->prop1 = new DummyClass(["foo"=>"abc123"])
$testArr1 = [
    "prop1" => ["foo" => "abc123"]
];
// should create an instance of ConcreteClass
// with ->prop1 = new DummyClass(["boo"=>"abc123def456"])
$testArr2 = [
    "prop1" => ["boo" => "abc123def456"]
];
$tc1 = new ConcreteClass($testArr1);
echo "Created TestClass1...<br><br>";
$tc2 = new ConcreteClass($testArr2);
echo "Created TestClass2...<br><br>";
die;
```

The results:

```
Creating new instance of ConcreteClass
Setting: ->prop1 = new DummyClass(array ( 'foo' => 'abc123', ))
Created TestClass1...

Creating new instance of ConcreteClass
Setting: ->prop1 = new abc123def456(array ( 'boo' => 'abc123def456', )) 
Error: assert(): abc123def456 !== DummyClass failed
```

Notice that the value of `$propClass` is `abc123def456` -- how did that happen?

**More Weirdness**

- Change the value of "abc123def456" to "12345678" and it will work.
- Change the value of "abc123def456" to "123456789" and it will not work.
- Omit the var_export(), and it will work. (Though, it may still break in other cases).

My gut tells me this is a PHP bug, but I might be doing something wrong, and/or this may be documented somewhere.  I would like some clarification, because as of right now my only reliable solution is to not cache the reflected $publicProps. This results in an unnecessary call to `ReflectionClass->getProperties()` every single time I create a new `ConcreteClass`, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: php7.4.9 runs fine, so bug was fixed. See the changelog - https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.9

Comment: Yeah looks like a bug. I've tried playing around with my local 7.4.0 on Windows and getting super weird outcomes, like not only odd results but also the script crashes if I execute it more than once. I've even reduced your code to [this tiny script](https://3v4l.org/dmCmE) and it still crashes that version of PHP if you run it twice (not sure if that's even related at this point lol).

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79820 is indeed this bug, with minimal reproduction here: https://3v4l.org/kchfm .  If you provide an answer I'll accept.

Comment: You can answer your own question, I just ran your code in fiddles and saw in what version the behaviour changed)

Comment: @u_mulder Ok, will do. Not sure what the etiquette is, I thought you might want to get points for answering or whatever. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in PHP:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79820

Minimal reproduction here: https://3v4l.org/kchfm

Fixed in 7.4.9: https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.9